# XML to JSON Conversion in R

Tags: r, json, xml

I've tried `library(rjson)` with 'XML' package. First I parsed the XML and converted it into list using `XML::xmlToList()` and converted that to JSON using `toJSON()` from rjson package.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

My source code:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(XML)
library(rjson)

xml_parse<-xmlParse(file = "path/book")
xml_root <- xmlRoot(xml_parse)
xml_list <- xmlToList(xml_root,addAttributes = T, simplify = F)
#rjson package
xml_rjson <-toJSON(xml_list)
cat(xml_rjson)
```

Converted JSON file from rjson:

```
  {
  "book": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Everyday Italian",
      ".attrs": {
        "lang": "en"
      }
    },
    "author": "Giada De Laurentiis",
    "year": "2005",
    "price": "30.00",
    ".attrs": {
      "category": "cooking"
    }
  },
  "book": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Harry Potter",
      ".attrs": {
        "lang": "en"
      }
    },
    "author": "J K. Rowling",
    "year": "2005",
    "price": "29.99",
    ".attrs": {
      "category": "children"
    }
  },
  "book": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Learning XML",
      ".attrs": {
        "lang": "en"
      }
    },
    "author": "Erik T. Ray",
    "year": "2003",
    "price": "39.95",
    ".attrs": {
      "category": "web"
    }
  }
}
```

Which is clearly wrong because of duplicate key "book" and no root name "bookstore".

The ideal JSON file would be as such:

```
{
  "bookstore": {
    "book": [
      {
        "-category": "cooking",
        "title": {
          "-lang": "en",
          "#text": "Everyday Italian"
        },
        "author": "Giada De Laurentiis",
        "year": "2005",
        "price": "30.00"
      },
      {
        "-category": "children",
        "title": {
          "-lang": "en",
          "#text": "Harry Potter"
        },
        "author": "J K. Rowling",
        "year": "2005",
        "price": "29.99"
      },
      {
        "-category": "web",
        "title": {
          "-lang": "en",
          "#text": "Learning XML"
        },
        "author": "Erik T. Ray",
        "year": "2003",
        "price": "39.95"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Looking forward for solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually, except for the missing root-level tag, the output you say is incorrect is actually the correct translation of the XML.  The `book` entries are all at level 1 (where the root is level zero).

Comment: When i tried it through online XML to JSON converter , it shows only one key name for book . Can check the given link     http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/?save=df0c3c3f-8a11-4dc3-9dc6-eb8d692e7b6a-xmltojson

Comment: @JimGarrison how can it be correct if the output isn't valid JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael notes, this is rly not a good idea. However, we're unlikely to convince you of that since not having an automagic conversion means doing work to ensure consistency and full reproducibility.

Since you seem to like that that web site does, I'm *pretty sure* it uses [`xml-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js) or something very close to it, so I threw together a small V8 wrapper package: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/blackmagic

There are *tons* of potential parameter settings for the `xml_to_json()` function so *please* look at that before any *"but it doesn't automagally do xyz for me"* comments.

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/blackmagic")

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>' -> books

cat(xml_to_json(books, spaces = 2, compact = TRUE, ignoreDeclaration = TRUE))

## {
##   "bookstore": {
##     "book": [
##       {
##         "_attributes": {
##           "category": "cooking"
##         },
##         "title": {
##           "_attributes": {
##             "lang": "en"
##           },
##           "_text": "Everyday Italian"
##         },
##         "author": {
##           "_text": "Giada De Laurentiis"
##         },
##         "year": {
##           "_text": "2005"
##         },
##         "price": {
##           "_text": "30.00"
##         }
##       },
##       {
##         "_attributes": {
##           "category": "children"
##         },
##         "title": {
##           "_attributes": {
##             "lang": "en"
##           },
##           "_text": "Harry Potter"
##         },
##         "author": {
##           "_text": "J K. Rowling"
##         },
##         "year": {
##           "_text": "2005"
##         },
##         "price": {
##           "_text": "29.99"
##         }
##       },
##       {
##         "_attributes": {
##           "category": "web"
##         },
##         "title": {
##           "_attributes": {
##             "lang": "en"
##           },
##           "_text": "Learning XML"
##         },
##         "author": {
##           "_text": "Erik T. Ray"
##         },
##         "year": {
##           "_text": "2003"
##         },
##         "price": {
##           "_text": "39.95"
##         }
##       }
##     ]
##   }
## }
```

Answer (score 0):

First point: there is no single definitive "correct" way to convert XML to JSON or vice versa. There are many different libraries that do it, and they all do it differently. It's unfortunate to choose one that actually generates incorrect JSON though.

Second point: if you know what XML you are starting with and you know what JSON you want to end up with, it's very unlikely that you will find a library that does the exact conversion you want.

In consequence, you're going to have to do some manual tweaking. You can potentially preprocess the input before conversion, or postprocess the output after conversion, or you can do the whole thing "by hand".

Doing the whole thing by hand isn't actually that difficult in XSLT (or probably in R, but I'm not familiar with that.)

My personal choice would be to use XSLT 3.0 to convert the XML to maps and arrays, and then serialize the result as JSON:

```
<xsl:output method="json" indent="yes">

<xsl:template match="booklist">
  <xsl:map-entry key="'booklist'">
    <xsl:map-entry key="'book'">
      <saxon:array>
        <xsl:for-each select="book">
          <saxon:array-member>
          <xsl:map>
           <xsl:map-entry key="'-category'" select="@category"/>
           <xsl:map-entry key="'title'">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
           </xsl:map-entry>
           <xsl:map-entry key="'author'" select="author"/>
           <xsl:map-entry key="'year'" select="year"/>
           <xsl:map-entry key="'price'" select="price"/>
         </xsl:map>
         </saxon:array-member>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </saxon:array>
   </xsl:map-entry>
 </xsl:map-entry>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <xsl:map-entry key="'-lang'" select="@lang"/>
  <xsl:map-entry key="'#text'" select="string(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

You could also try, of course, to generalize some of these rules, e.g. to have a template rule that matches all attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your response.